# I don't get this x86 Assembly Inline code

Tags: inline-assembly

```
void a(DWORD b) {
   __asm {
       mov ecx, b 
          mov eax, [ecx]
          call dword ptr[eax + 12]
   }
}
```

What I don't get about this is that its moving "b" over to the ECX register, then moving it back to the EAX register, and then calling the function located within the EAX register.

Is it inefficient code? Is it supposed to be like that?
Why can't I do:

```
__asm {
   mov eax, b
   call dword ptr[eax + 12]
}
```

I'm really confused here. Am I missing something about the general concept about registers in assembly?

Comment: You should look up the syntax for the inline assembly. `mov ecx, b` moves the **address** of `b` to the `ecx` register, then `mov eax, [ecx]` moves **what `ecx` points to (`[ecx]`)** into the `eax` register. In short, `eax` gets the value at the location given by `b`.

Comment: So is it inefficient code? Like I said before, can't I just do this: __asm {
   mov eax, b
   call dword ptr[eax + 12]
}

Comment: No it's not the same. Like I said before :). Your suggested change does something different. In the first set of code, `eax` ends up with the *contents* of where the address of `b` points. In the second (your) set of code, `eax` ends up with the *address* of `b` itself.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks!